# Disabling select options within modal window based on previous select options being disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple select dropdown in a modal window that prepopulates based on identical select dropdowns on the main page (I am using Foundation 4). On both dropdown menus, there is a certain combination that the user cannot pick. I have all this working, except when the modal window comes up the user can make an illegal selection at first, unless they change the option and then try to change it again. I need it to make the illegal option greyed out when the modal window pops up, and not after they change the selection on the modal window like I have it now. Can anyone help me?

Here is the HTML:

```
<!-- THE ON-PAGE DROPDOWN -->
<div id="choose">
<h1><strong>Choose your FREE bag of Coffee</strong></h1>
<!--START BLENDS-->
<div class="row register">
<p class="large-1 columns " style="text-align:right;"><em>*</em></p>
<div class="large-11 columns">
<select name="blend1" id="blend1">
<option value="">Choose Blend</option> 
<option value="">&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;</option> 
<option value="1"> Light</option> 
<option value="2">Medium</option> 
<option value="3">Dark</option> 
<option value="4">Robust</option> 
<option value="5">French Vanilla</option> 
<option value="6">Caramel Vanilla</option> 
<option value="7">Hazelnut &amp; Cinnamon</option> 
<option value="8">Passionata &mdash; Chocolate Truffles</option> 
</select>
</div>
</div>
<!--END BLENDS-->
<fieldset>

<div class="row register">
<p class="large-1 columns " style="text-align:right;"><em>*</em></p>
<div class="large-11 columns">
<select name="grind1" id="grind1">
<option value="">Choose Grind</option> 
<option value="">&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;</option> 
<option value="1">Ground</option> 
<option value="2">Whole Bean</option> 
</select>
</div>    
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div class="row register">
<p class="large-1 columns " style="text-align:right;"><em>*</em></p>
<div class="large-11 columns">
<select name="type1" id="type1">
<option value="">Choose Type</option> 
<option value="">&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;</option> 
<option value="1">Regular</option> 
<option value="2">Decaf</option> 
</select>
</div>    
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>

<!-- END OF MAIN PAGE DROPDOWN -->

<!-- MODAL WINDOW HTML -->                          

<div class="choice" >
<select name="blend2" id="blend2">
<option value="">Choose Blend</option> 
<option value="">&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;</option> 
<option value="1">Light</option> 
<option value="2">Medium</option> 
<option value="3">Dark</option> 
<option value="4">Robust</option> 
<option value="5">French Vanilla</option> 
<option value="6">Caramel Vanilla</option> 
<option value="7">Hazelnut &amp; Cinnamon</option> 
<option value="8">Chocolate Truffles</option> 
</select>
</div>
<div class="choice2">
<select name="grind2" id="grind2">
<option value="">Choose Grind</option> 
<option value="">&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;</option> 
<option value="1">Ground</option> 
<option value="2">Whole Bean</option> 
</select>



<select name="type2" id="type2">
<option value="">Choose Type</option> 
<option value="">&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;&mdash;</option> 
<option value="1">Regular</option> 
<option value="2">Decaf</option> 
</select>
</div>
```

Here is the JS/jQuery:

```
<script>
$("#blend1").change(function () {
if ($(this).val() == "1") {
$("#blend2").val("1");
}
if ($(this).val() == "2") {
$("#blend2").val("2");
}
if ($(this).val() == "3") {
$("#blend2").val("3");
}
if ($(this).val() == "4") {
$("#blend2").val("4");
}
if ($(this).val() == "5") {
$("#blend2").val("5");
}
if ($(this).val() == "6") {
$("#blend2").val("6");
}
if ($(this).val() == "7") {
$("#blend2").val("7");
}
if ($(this).val() == "8") {
$("#blend2").val("8");
}
});

$("#grind1").change(function () {
if ($(this).val() == "1") {
$("#grind2").val("1");
}
if ($(this).val() == "2") {
$("#grind2").val("2");
}
});

$("#type1").change(function () {
if ($(this).val() == "1") {
$("#type2").val("1");
}
if ($(this).val() == "2") {
$("#type2").val("2");
}
});
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$("select[name='grind1']").on("change", function(e) {
if ($('option:selected', this).val() == 2) {
$("select[name='type1'] option[value=2]").attr('disabled', true);
} else {
$("select[name='type1'] option[value=2]").attr('disabled', false);       
}
});

$("select[name='type1']").on("change", function(e) {
if ($('option:selected', this).val() == 2) {
$("select[name='grind1'] option[value=2]").attr('disabled', true);
} else {
$("select[name='grind1'] option[value=2]").attr('disabled', false);       
}
});

});

</script>

<!-- NO BONUS UPSELL -->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() {

$("select[name='grind2']").on("change", function(e) {
if ($('option:selected', this).val() == 2) {
$("select[name='type2'] option[value=2]").attr('disabled', true);
} else {
$("select[name='type2'] option[value=2]").attr('disabled', false);       
}
});

$("select[name='type2']").on("change", function(e) {
if ($('option:selected', this).val() == 2) {
$("select[name='grind2'] option[value=2]").attr('disabled', true);
} else {
$("select[name='grind2'] option[value=2]").attr('disabled', false);       
}
});

});

</script>
```

If anyone could help me, that would be fantastic!

Comment: When I've done things like this in the past, I added a validation function to the on-open of the modal.  That function goes through and checks the various conditions and enables/disables the select inputs as necessary.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that, would it be its own function?

Comment: You would write your own function in the javascript, like          function validate(){..........}   and put your logic in there.  That's not the only way to do it but it is where I would start.